# Validating a String in a Class List C#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Im making a project in C# Console Application and it is a Sports Club Management Software for school. I created a Class List Athletes and I got several paramenters, one of it is the Athlete's ID... My question is, when I choose the "Add Athlete" option, how can I check if there´s already an ID in the whole list. You probably thinking: "Ohh... Well its preety ez, just a do while, and a for method in it and use the Contain method..." Well Ive tryed that and I didn't quite got it... Ive been programming for some months now... Its not that I am a very skilled programmer but :/ ...

1. This is what I tryed doing:

   ```
       do
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < Athletes.Count; i++)
           {
               if (Athletes[i].id.Contains(id))
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("ID already exists, please insert another ID!");
                   Console.WriteLine();
                   Console.Write("Id: ");
                   id = Console.ReadLine();
               }
           }
       } while (Athletes[i]);
   ```

the thing is, as you can see, I cant use the [i] in the do while what makes it impossible to go through the list. I thought about getting a boolean but Im not really into booleans. Its probably a preety ez to fix problem but I really cant figger it out. Thanks guys. :)

Comment: It would be really helpful to have the definition of the `Athletes` variable and the class it's a list of...

Comment: Can you give more information about **Athletes[i].id** and **id**? Are they strings?

Comment: General advice, especially since you are a beginner: Do not start with writing code. Approach your task/problem in an intuitive way. For example with paper. Write on a sheet of paper some athletes (and all the relevant information like an ID). Then think up an ID and go through the list on the paper. If you find that ID being already on the paper, what would you do then? (Be very precise about what you would do). etc. etc. and so on. This way it's much easier to nail down the process. If you understand/know what you do with that list on the paper, you can transform the same process into code.

Comment: Ok @elgonzo thanks, I will delete this question since I just figured it out. thank you. I usualy do so, when Im at school. But when I am at home I just jump at straight coding... Guess I will start doing it differently! :)

Comment: The better answer is to use Dictionary instead of List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that `Athletes` is a `List<Athlete>` or something of that nature?  You can check if any member of a generic list meets a given predicate with `.Any()`.  For example:

```
if (Athletes.Any(a => a.id == id))
```

If `Any()` returns `true` then that means at least one member of the list satisfies the condition.

Comment: Thank you, I used it and then since I was going through a do while and inside of it a foreach i just had to use a goto to break the loop. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq; 

  ...

  // Keep asking id... 
  while (true) {
    if (!Athletes.Any(athlete => athlete.ID == id)) 
      break; // ... until id is not found

    Console.WriteLine("ID already exists, please insert another ID!");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Id: ");

    id = Console.ReadLine(); 
    //TODO: validate id here 
 }
```

Please notice, that you have to *validate* the user input: what if user write, say `"bla-bla-blas"` as `id`?

Answer (score 0):

Override `Equals()` in Athlete class.

```
public override bool Equals (Object otherAthlete) {
    if (otherAthlete == null) return false;
    if (! otherAthlete is typeof(Athlete)) return false;

    return this.ID == otherAthlete.ID;
}
```

That will make `List<Athelete>.Contains()` work. No need to iterate.

```
public void Add (Athlete newAthlete) {
    if (newAthelete == null) return;

    if (! athleteList.Contains(newAthlete)) 
       athleteList.Add(newAthlete);

}
```